# How to implement `where` to filter data in flutter list?

Tags: flutter, filter, flutter-listview

I am new at learning flutter, I am trying to implement `where` on the `List` to filter data, but I a getting it totally wrong, please guide me the correct implmentations

Implementation

```
 List filterproducts=   productslist.where(widget.bomdatareceived[0]['purchase_items'][0]['product_code'].contains(widget.product_code));
```

ERROR

```
type 'bool' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => bool'
```

JSON data

```
"purchase_items": [
               {
                     
                   "product_code": "61",
                   "name": "SPINNING",
                   "bom_catalog_item": "327",
                  },
                  {
                     
                   "product_code": "61",
                   "name": "SPINNING",
                   "bom_catalog_item": "390",
                   },
                   {
                     
                    "product_code": "65",
                    "name": "DYING",
                    "bom_catalog_item": "1056",
                   }
                   ]
```

Comment: what do you mean  by widget ? a constatnt ?

Comment: @Merym yes, `widget.product_code` is a string value

Answer (score 0):

```
List filterproducts=   productslist.where((i) => widget.bomdatareceived[0]['purchase_items'][0]['product_code'].contains(widget.product_code));
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your answer, it is giving me error of `type 'WhereIterable<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'` , please guide further

Answer (score 0):

```
List filterproducts= productslist.where((f) => f.bomdatareceived[0]['purchase_items'][0]['product_code'].contains(widget.product_code)).toList();
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your answer, it is giving me error of type 'WhereIterable<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' , please guide further , or shall I provide more data, like the JSON data structure?

Comment: @Harry West did you try it ?

Comment: Yes, I tried but it did not resolve the issue, it was giving me error `The method 'where' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: where(Closure: (dynamic) => dynamic) `, if some more information is required, please let me know

Comment: can you print this productslist

Comment: I have added the JSON data on whiich this has to be implemented

Answer (score 0):

```
var filterproducts=[];
filterproducts.addAll(widget.bomdatareceived[0]['purchase_items'][0]['product_code']
        .where((element) => element.contains(widget.product_code))
        .toList());
```

Comment: HI , I implemented your suggestion it giving me this error, The method 'where' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: where(Closure: (dynamic) => dynamic)

Comment: filterproducts.addAll(purchase_items
        .where((item) => item["proc_code"] ==widget.product_code)
        .toList());

Answer (score 0):

[image]

the results :

[image]

the code :

```
  var purchase_items = [
               {
                     
                   "proc_code": "61",
                   "name": "SPINNING",
                   "bom_catalog_item": "327",
                  },
                  {
                     
                   "proc_code": "61",
                   "name": "SPINNING",
                   "bom_catalog_item": "390",
                   },
                   {
                     
                    "proc_code": "65",
                    "name": "DYING",
                    "bom_catalog_item": "1056",
                   }
                   ];
 List<Map<String,String>> filterproducts = new List<Map<String,String>>();


filterproducts = purchase_items.where((f) => f['proc_code'] == ('61')).toList();
  print(filterproducts);
```